# Unable to run SAConfettiView on Xcode Playgrounds

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I am trying to make the [SAConfettiView](https://github.com/sudeepag/SAConfettiView) framework to work in Xcode playgrounds. Though, when I use the code above the confetti animation isn't showing up.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

var view = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
var confettiView: SAConfettiView!
confettiView = SAConfettiView(frame: view.bounds)
confettiView.type = .Star
view.addSubview(confettiView)
confettiView.startConfetti()
view.backgroundColor = .red
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

What am I doing wrong?

[Download playground here](https://ufile.io/75242)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `ConfettiView.swift` in the `Sources` folder does not load the images properly.

Replace their `image(for type: ConfettiType) -> UIImage?` method with this one:

```
func image(for type: ConfettiType) -> UIImage? {
    var fileName: String

    switch type {
    case .Confetti:
        fileName = "confetti"
    case .Triangle:
        fileName = "triangle"
    case .Star:
        fileName = "star"
    case .Diamond:
        fileName = "diamond"
    case let .Image(customImage):
        return customImage
    }

    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "png"),
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else
    {
        return nil
    }

    return UIImage(data: data)
}
```

where I use `Bundle.main.url` to load the confetti images properly.

[image]